# After installing Linux, preinstalled Windows 8 is not in boot entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

i have installed Linux Mint beside to preinstalled windows 8.
After the installation, in grub2 menu there is no windows 8 entry.
Also the partitions are not shown..

the tool boot-repair dont help me..

here is the boot-repair report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729336/

How can i fix this ?

thank you in advance

Comment: It might be that you have no Windows. You must not have used the side by side install but the install to entire drive option. You only show a Windows boot loader in the MBR and Windows boot loader efi files in the efi partition. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI, but you have no NTFS Windows partition.

Answer (score 2):

As user Olfred pointed out, from your boot repair:

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,465,149,167 1,465,149,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       999,423       997,376 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         999,424 1,440,442,367 1,439,442,944 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3   1,440,442,368 1,465,147,391    24,705,024 Swap partition (Linux)
```

You dedicated the majority of your sectors to the Data partition (linux). Total of 1.46 billion sectors, 1.43 bil sectors allocated to linux partition.

:(

Your windows install is gone, along with any data you had in it. Best you can do is reinstall windows. Installing Windows have the nasty tendency to break your grub. First make a live-usb of Ubuntu, install Windows, then head to this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Just make sure you do a "side-by-side" install this time :)

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally deleted a partition that Windows was installed. So now you need to restore your parsonal files and (re)install Windows:

- to restore files (it's not 100% guaranteed) you need to plug HDD to
  computer with preinstalled Windows and use something like GetDataBack
  for NTFS (it's commercial, but I can not recommend any other in your
  situation). **REMEMBER: do not use (write to) your HDD - it decreases the chance of successfull data restoration.**
- to install window you need to shrink your ext4 partition with gparted, boot from
  Window installation DVD, select "Install to unallocated space". After all, reinstall
  grub2 (http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).

Good luck!